# Why does lsusb return my Motorola Razr D3 as "HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)"?

Tags: lsusb, htc

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bb4:2012 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)
```

Is this a bug and needs to be reported? If so, how?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right line? What's the other `lsusb` output?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids `0bb4` is indeed HTC. So your phone presents the ID of this manufacturer.

You would have to ask them about the why.

Comment: Could be that the phone is a cheap knock-off based on a HTC device.